# GUARDAR DATOS DE UN COMBO BOX A MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing, combobox, crud

Les comentare el problema que tengo. Tego un ComboBox en Java el cual esta conectado a una BD(Mysql). El ComboBox me carga perfectamente los datos de la BD, en este caso el nombre de unos usuarios. Sin embargo, al momento de yo programar el botón de 'Guardar' no se como  guardar el Item que he seleccionado en el ComboBox a la Base de datos..

Este es el código que me carga los datos de la BD

```
modeloCombo = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String [] {});
    initComponents();
    //Instancion al clase productos
    productos objproductos = new productos();

    //ResultSet
    ResultSet estados;
    //Instancio la clase estados
    estados = objproductos.consultarEstado();
    try {
        //Recorremos el resultado generado por la consulta
        while(estados.next()){
            //Con el metodo addElement vamos a agregar cada resultado al comboBox
            modeloCombo.addElement(new Estado(estados.getInt("nit"), estados.getString("nombre")));                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Consulta no hecha"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Este es el objeto que uso cada vez que necesito el ComboBox(Esta dentro de la programcion el botón)

```
//Creamos un objeto
    Estado objEstado = (Estado) cboEstado.getSelectedItem();
    //Asignamos el atributo del objeto seleccionado en el combo.
    int estado = objEstado.getNit(); //Ya aquí tenemos el id del estado seleccionado.

 int provedores_nit;
 //En el if de abajo estoy seleccionando el ID del objeto y luego asignandoselo a la variable provedores_nit para luego guardarlo en la BD
 if(cboEstado.getSelectedItem() ==  objEstado.getNit()){
        provedores_nit = objEstado.getNit();
    }
```

Comment: hola no he trabajado con java y sus componentes como combobox, pero intenta con esto..  *jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()*

Comment: Lo intentaré y te aviso.

Comment: añade mas información como tienes tu sql statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy sencillo, primero debes tener el nombre de tu combobox, pongamos este ejemplo

nombre del combobox: **cbDocumentos**

Creamos una variable de tipo String: **documentos_cb**

Ahora para obtener el item seleccionado debes hacer esto

```
String documentos_cb;

documentos_cb = cbDocumentos.getSelectedItem().ToString();
```

Aqui estas mandando el item seleccionado del combobox a la variale **documentos_cb**

al momento de hacer el update o insert, en el index de la tabla simplemente coloca la variable documentos_cb

algo asi, porque estoy suponiendo, pero dejare este ejemplo con un insert:

```
pstIngresarDatos.setString(8, documentos_cb);
```

y bueno para un update, seria lo mismo :)

```
 pstUpdateDatos.setString(8, documentos_cb);
```

Espero haberte ayudado :D

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó a la perfección!